# SELECT_IDENTITY() not working in php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

***Scenario:***

I have a SQL Query `INSERT INTO dbo.Grades (Name, Capacity, SpringPressure) VALUES ('{PHP}',{PHP}, {PHP})`

The data types are correct.

I need to now get the latest `IDENTIY` which is `GradeID`.

I have tried the following after consulting MSDN and StackOverflow:

- `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` which works in SQL Management Studio but does not in my php code. (Which is at the bottom), I have also tried to add `GO` in between the two 'parts' - if I can call them that - but still to no avail.
- The next thing I tried, `SELECT @@IDENTITY` Still to no avail.
- Lastly, I tried `PDO::lastInsertId()` which did not seem to work.

What I need it for is mapping a temporary ID I assign to the object to a new permanent ID I get back from the database to refer to when I insert an object that is depended on that newly inserted object.

***Expected Results:***

Just to return the newly inserted row's `IDENTITY`.

***Current Results:***

It returns it but is `NULL`.

```
[Object]
    0: Object
       ID: null
```

This piece pasted above is the result from `print json_encode($newID);` as shown below.

***Notes,***

This piece of code is running in a file called `save_grades.php` which is called from a `ajax` call. The call is working, it is just not working as expected.

As always, I am always willing to  learn, please feel free to give advice and or criticize my thinking. Thanks

***Code:***

```
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($grades); $i++) { 
     $grade = $grades[$i];

     $oldID = $grade->GradeID;
     $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Grades (Name, Capacity, SpringPressure) VALUES ('" . $grade->Name . "',". $grade->Capacity .", ".$grade->SpringPressure .")";

     try {
        $sqlObject->executeNonQuery($query);
        $query =  "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID";
        $newID = $sqlObject->executeQuery($query);
        print json_encode($newID);
     } catch(Exception $e) {
        print json_encode($e);
     }


     $gradesDictionary[] = $oldID => $newID;

}
```

***EDIT #1***

Here is the code for my custom wrapper. (Working with getting the `lastInsertId()`)

```
class MSSQLConnection
    {
            private $connection;
            private $statement;
            public function __construct(){
                    $connection = null;
                    $statement =null;
            }

            public function createConnection() {

                    $serverName = "localhost\MSSQL2014";
                    $database = "{Fill In}";
                    $userName = "{Fill In}";
                    $passWord = "{Fill In}";

                    try {
                       $this->connection = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=$database", $userName, $passWord);
                       $this->connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                    }
                    catch( PDOException $e ) {
                       die("Connection Failed, please contact system administrator.");
                    }

                    if ($this->connection == null) {
                            die("Connection Failed, please contact system administrator.");
                    }
            }

            public function executeQuery($queryString) {
                    $results = array();
                    $this->statement = $this->connection->query( $queryString );
                    while ( $row = $this->statement->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){
                       array_push($results, $row);
                    }
                    return $results;
            }

    public function executeNonQuery($queryString) {
                    $numRows = $this->connection->exec($queryString);
            }

            public function getLastInsertedID() {
                    return $this->connection->lastInsertId();
            }

            public function closeConnection() {
                    $this->connection = null;
                    $this->statement = null;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Well, the PDO way is [PDO::lastInsertId()](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) but whether it works depend on the driver (you don't say). I also don't recognise those method names—are you using a wrapper on top of PDO?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, Yes, I am. I custom wrote a wrapper to handle that for me. If you are keen to see it, here it is: http://pastebin.com/Tz3Li80k

Comment: ... which has `public function getLastInsertedID(){}` anyway :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, indeed. I put it there :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is PDO right ? better drop these custom function wrapper...

```
$json = array();

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($grades); $i++) { 
    //Query DB
    $grade = $grades[$i];   
    $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Grades (Name, Capacity, SpringPressure) 
              VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $success = $stmt->execute(array($grade->Name,
                                    $grade->Capacity,
                                    $grade->SpringPressure));

    //Get Ids
    $newId = $conn->lastInsertId();
    $oldId = $grade->GradeID;

    //build JSON
    if($success){
        $json[] = array('success'=> True,
                        'oldId'=>$oldId, 'newId'=>$newId);
    }else{
        $json[] = array('success'=> False,
                        'oldId'=>$oldId);
    }
}
print json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, thanks. I misspelled the `$conn->lastInsertId()` I used `$conn->lastInsertedId()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the query in this form
"Select max(GradeID) from dbo.Grades"

Comment: He probably wants the ID generated by his last query, not someone else's.

Comment: it returns last ID generated because 'Identity column' increments the value so max(ID)= last insert ID

Comment: There's absolutely no guarantee about that in a multi-user environment.

Comment: yes sir, I have failed to in that case. Thank you sir
Is it may work in stored procedure ...?